# Why does ReactJS sets state when calling setState inside setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

In a simple reactJS class, this.setState() didn't actually set the state. I know it is called asynchronously but even when the component renders again, the state wasn't mutated. So `this.state.showModal` is `false` when component is mounted (as expected) then it is `true` "forever".

here's a simple example :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    }

    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this)
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this)
  }
  showModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: true })
  }
  hideModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: false })
  }
  render () {
    console.log(this.state.showModal) // Outputs true even after the hideModal() call

    return (
      <Components>
        <div onClick={this.showModal}>
          {
            this.state.showModal === true
            ? <Modal
              handles={handles}
              close={this.hideModal}
            />
            : '+'
          }
        </div>
      </Components>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the Modal Component :

```
class Modal extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='configurator-modal'>
        <button className='close' onClick={this.props.close}> x </button>
        Modal
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But, when I replace the `hideModal` function with a timeout like this :

`setTimeout(() => this.setState({ showModal: false }), 0)`

The state is mutated and rendered as intended.

I'm just wondering why ReactJS could possibly reset state internally or prevent a state from mutating ?

Edit : Calls to hideModal and showModal added

Comment: You need to show how you are calling `hidemodal` ?

Comment: can you tell us how you call the `hideModal` method?

Comment: I edited my post, sorry I tried to simplify the code a bit too much.

Comment: @3Dos Still not clear. How you are calling `showModal`?

Comment: My last edit should be complete by now. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no plunker to play around, I am going to take a guess.

`div` being the parent of `<Modal>`, when click event is triggered on the `Modal`, it is also being propagated to `div`. So `showModal` state is set to `false` by `hideModal()` function and set back to `true` by `showModal()` function.

When `hideModal()` uses `setTimeout()`, it is getting called after `showModal()` is called.

Try adding `event.stopPropagation` in `hideModal()` function, it might work.

Alternatively, you should add `showModal()` as onClick handler for the `+` sign instead of whole parent div. Please find the code below:

```
<Components>
    <div>
      {
        this.state.showModal === true
        ? <Modal
          handles={handles}
          close={this.hideModal}
        />
        : <div onClick={this.showModal}>'+'</div>
      }
    </div>
  </Components>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. I absolutely didn't thought of that but it seems super logic !

Answer (score 0):

You have a `click` handler on the parent element too which call the `showModal` and change the state to true.

When you click `close` button, that will call `hideModal` function, which will change the state to `false` but that click will propagate to parent element as well, which will call `showModal` which make it `true` again. Therefore it always remains `true`.

**Solution:** Remove `showModal` click handler from the parent element and put it where exactly you want it to be (i guess you want it on `+`).